# Remove message from RabbitMQ when consumed by listener. Cannot determine ReplyTo message exception

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Using SpringBoot.

I have created an TopicExchange which accepts messages and directs them to two queues based on a routingKey present in the message.

Messages are sent via :

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend('in-out-topic', 'inbound.queue.route.key', payload)
```

Messages are received:

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "inbound-queue")
  def onInboundMessage(def message) {
    try {
      log.debug("Received inbound message: ${message.messageId} on inbound queue listener", message)

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("Inbound message exception: ${ex.getMessage()}")
      return;
    }
    return message.payload
  }
```

But when my listener (consumer) receives a message I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set.
```

- Should I create a dummy response exchange via RabbitMQ dashboard?
- Hardcode a non existent replyTo property?
- Configure the existing topicExchange or Queues somehow?

I just want the message being removed from the corresponding queue when consumed by my message listener.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is in the end of method, here:

```
return message.payload
```

If you really are not going to send reply and we indeed see that by expectations via `convertAndSend()`, then you shouldn’t return anything from the `@RabbitListener` method. Otherwise, as you are experiencing, the return from such a method is treated as an attempt to send a reply.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven. Pay attention to the `Reply Management` paragraph.

Comment: If exception occurs in my local listener then I still get the aforementioned error. So if I get an invalid message, upon exception it will be requeued by default and then again sent to my listener. Because I don't wont to loose messages, I should then manually remove the message from the queue causing the exceptions locally? Or configure some sort of queue for such messages? Then I would need the reply-to property set?

Comment: @RabbitListener annotation has two new attributes: errorHandler and returnExceptions that will do. Thanks!